# Using graphics.py and the keyboard, how can I make a character move based upon keyboard input?

Tags: python, graphics, keyboard

I am a very beginner python coder, and just started to tinker around with graphics.py, so please excuse my probably horrible code. All I want is to know how to use a keyboard/graphics function that works. Right now if I run this, it does not move the character the way I want it to. I want to be able to press the WASD keys, and have the square on the screen move.

```
from graphics import *
import keyboard

point1 = Point(680, 420)
point2 = Point(720, 380)


class Player:
    def __init__(self, char, window):
        self.p1 = char
        self.win = window

    def create_Player(self):
        self.p1.setFill(color_rgb(0, 255, 0))
        self.p1.draw(self.win)
        self.win.getMouse()
        self.win.close()

    def movement(self):
        global point1, point2
        if keyboard.is_pressed("d"):
            self.p1.move(10, 0)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            self.p1.move(-10, 0)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
            self.p1.move(0, 10)
        if keyboard.is_pressed("w"):
            self.p1.move(0, -10)



p1 = Player(Rectangle(point1, point2), GraphWin("mini graphic game", 1400, 800))
p1.create_Player()
while True:
    p1.movement()
```

Comment: all GUIs have own functions to work with mouse and keys and they don't need module ` keyboard - and I would expect the same in `graphics.py`. And if I remeber `graphics.py` uses module `tkinter` which has `bind()` to assign function to key/mouse event.

Comment: yes, i am a very starting level beginner. I tried to read about it, but it was hard to understand for me. I tried doing _if(self.win.getKey()=="w")_ however, it also did not work. I know I am probably missing something in the graphics.py, but I just can't seem to understand. That's why I reverted to keyboard, which seemed to be a little easier to understand.

Comment: your main problem is that you don't know that every GUI runs loop which gets key/mouse event from system and sends them to widgets, and later redraw windget. And in your code `self.win.getMouse()` runs this loop which ends working when you close window - so all you keys are checking after closing window - so it useless. Probably you use `getKey` in the same moment so you check it after closing window. It has to be done in totally different way.

Comment: BTW: method which you try to do can works in PyGame because you have to write own even loop from scratch - so you can do what you want - but in GUI you use existing event loop and it is OK when you creae classic windows program, but now in game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All GUIs runs event loop which works until you close window and it blocks other elements and you have to learn how to works with this loop.

In your code this loop is in `self.win.getMouse()` so your loop runs after closing window.

Using code from `self.win.getMouse()` I created own loop which runs the same elements and `p1.movement()` which uses `self.win.lastKey` to get last clicked key. At this moment problem is that this value keep last key even when you release it so object moves even if you don't press keys. It use hidden `_onKey()` which means `onKeyPress` but code would need also `_onKeyRelease()`. Maybe later I made it.

BTW: [graphics.py source code](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Zelle%27s_Graphics.py_for_Python_3) which I checked to get these informations.

```
from graphics import *
import time

# --- classes ---

class Player:
    def __init__(self, window, char):
        self.p1 = char
        self.win = window

    def create(self):
        self.p1.setFill(color_rgb(0, 255, 0))
        self.p1.draw(self.win)

    def movement(self):
        if self.win.lastKey == "d":
            self.p1.move(10, 0)
        if self.win.lastKey == "a":
            self.p1.move(-10, 0)
        if self.win.lastKey == "s":
            self.p1.move(0, 10)
        if self.win.lastKey == "w":
            self.p1.move(0, -10)

# --- main ---

point1 = Point(680, 420)
point2 = Point(720, 380)

win = GraphWin("mini graphic game", 1400, 800)

p1 = Player(win, Rectangle(point1, point2))
p1.create()

while not win.isClosed():
    p1.movement()

    win.update()
    time.sleep(.1)

win.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** Version which stops player when you don't press key. I added `onKeyPress` and `onKeyRelease` to set value in `self.keys["d"] = True/False` which can be used to run and stop player.

I also added enemies which move in random direction.

```
from graphics import *
import time
import random

# --- classes ---

class Window(GraphWin):

    def __init__(self, title="Graphics Window",
                 width=200, height=200, autoflush=True):
        super().__init__(title, width, height, autoflush)

        self.bind_all("<KeyPress>",   self._onKeyPress)
        self.bind_all("<KeyRelease>", self._onKeyRelease)

        self.keys = dict() # dictionary for `keys[event.keysym] = True/False`

    def _onKeyPress(self, event):
        self.keys[event.keysym] = True

    def _onKeyRelease(self, event):
        self.keys[event.keysym] = False


class Player:
    def __init__(self, window, char, color):
        self.win = window
        self.rect = char
        self.color = color

        self.rect.setFill(self.color)
        self.rect.draw(self.win)

    def movement(self):
        # use `keys.get("d")` instead of `keys["d"]` because `"d"` may not exists in dictionary `key`
        if self.win.keys.get("d"):
            self.rect.move(10, 0)
        if self.win.keys.get("a"):
            self.rect.move(-10, 0)
        if self.win.keys.get("s"):
            self.rect.move(0, 10)
        if self.win.keys.get("w"):
            self.rect.move(0, -10)

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, window, rect, color):
        self.win = window
        self.rect = rect
        self.color = color

        self.rect.setFill(self.color)
        self.rect.draw(self.win)

    def movement(self):
        dx = random.randint(-30, 30)
        dy = random.randint(-30, 30)
        self.rect.move(dx, dy)

# --- main ---

point1 = Point(680, 420)
point2 = Point(720, 380)

point3 = Point(180, 420)
point4 = Point(220, 380)

win = Window("mini graphic game", 1400, 800)

player = Player(win, Rectangle(point1, point2), color_rgb(0, 255, 0))
enemies = [Enemy(win, Rectangle(point3, point4), color_rgb(255, 0, 0)) for _ in range(10)]

while not win.isClosed():
    player.movement()
    for e in enemies:
        e.movement()

    win.update()
    time.sleep(.1)

win.close()
```